# Как закрепить UI элемнты (кнопки) на 3д объекте на сцене в Unity

Tags: unity3d, ui, 3d, unity3d-ui

Как мне закрепить UI элемент на игровой сцене за 3D объектом, чтобы при изменении расстояния, изменялся и его размер, чтобы кнопки были всегда повернуты на игрока и т.д.?

Если я верно понимаю, это необходимо делать не на привычном `Canvas`, а как-то при помощи `Raycast`, но пока я сомневаюсь.

Comment: Ok Google : world position to canvas position

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToViewportPoint.html